# Contour Integration in the complex plane

Tags: integration

I need to find the result of the following:
$$\int_C \left( e^z - \frac{1}{z} \right) $$

Where $C$ is the lower half of the circle with radius $1$ and centre $0$, negatively oriented.

**Note:** This is for a homework assignment. I do not want the answer, I am stuck.

When I applied the follow:

$$\int f(z) dz = \int f[z(t)]z'(t) dt\,,\;\;\text{ where}\;\; \;t\in[-\pi, 0]$$

I parametrise $z(t)=e^{i t}$

and I end up with this

$$\int \left( e^{e^{i t}} - \frac{1}{e^{i t}} \right ) d t$$

Which I do not know how to do.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Your function is  analytic on the given path (and in a simply connected region containing it, if you want) , and it has a rather easy potential function (if you think as in multi variable real analyis) = a primitive function there, given by

$$f(z)=e^z-\text{Log}\,z$$

Thus, you only need to know the value of the primitive on the end points.

Answer (score 2):

Split into two pieces.  The second piece, $1/z$, you may simply parametrize as you have done to get

$$\int_{2 \pi}^{\pi}  \frac{i e^{i \theta} d\theta}{e^{i \theta}} $$

For the first piece, note that $e^z$ is analytic everywhere so that the integral over any closed contour is zero.  Thus, close the semicircle along the real axis, and you may then express the integral over the semicircle as the negative of the integral over the real line across the diameter, or

$$-\int_{-1}^1 dx \, e^x $$

Comment: When I integrate over the real axis, as above, I get a result $2e^z$, I am confused about that. Can you assist?

Comment: @user141183: I'm confused as to how you got a $z$ in there.  The integral of $e^x$ is $e^x$.  Evaluate at endpoints. Subtract.  Done.

Comment: Serious LOL, screen resolution, I literally thought I saw $-\int_{-1}^{1} dx e^z$